# How to get transformer Model running on GPU

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, transformer-model

Hi so I have a transformer model that only seems to be running on cpu and whenever I try to get it to run on cuda it throws an error saying that two devices are present.

I am using the transformer model found here https://towardsdatascience.com/build-your-own-transformer-from-scratch-using-pytorch-84c850470dcb .

I have been interfacing with it in order to try and get it to lear off of a pandas dataframe.

this is my code to interact with the model

```
src_vocab_size = 100160
tgt_vocab_size = 79258
d_model = 512
num_heads = 8
num_layers = 6
d_ff = 2048
max_seq_length = 100
dropout = 0.1

transformer = Transformer(src_vocab_size, tgt_vocab_size, d_model, num_heads, num_layers, d_ff, max_seq_length, dropout)


enctype = "cl100k_base"
encoding = tiktoken.get_encoding(enctype)
df = pd.read_csv('/home/rdrori/geneLocationLookupNetwork/Translation_Admiration/locus.tsv', sep='\t', header = None)
df.columns = ['Column1', 'Column2', 'Column3', 'Column4']
df['Column2'] = df['Column2'].str.cat(df['Column3'], sep=' ', na_rep='')
#print(df.iloc[886, 0])
#print(df.iloc[886, 1])
#print(df.iloc[886, 2])
#src_data = torch.randint(1, 50, (64, 50))
#print(src_data)
source_list = [(encoding.encode(text)) for text in df['Column1']]
trgt_list = [(encoding.encode(text)) for text in df['Column2']]

torch.set_printoptions(sci_mode=False)
source_tensors = []
for sublist in source_list:
    temptensor = torch.tensor(sublist[:16])  # Truncate sublist to length 16
    if len(temptensor) < 16:
        padded_tensor = torch.zeros(16)  # Create a tensor of zeros
        padded_tensor[:len(temptensor)] = temptensor  # Copy sublist elements into the padded tensor
        temptensor = padded_tensor
    source_tensors.append(temptensor)
    
    
target_tensors = []
for slis in trgt_list:
    temporarytens = torch.tensor(slis[:16])  # Truncate sublist to length 16
    if len(temporarytens) < 16:
        padded_tensy = torch.zeros(16)  # Create a tensor of zeros
        padded_tensy[:len(temporarytens)] = temporarytens  # Copy sublist elements into the padded tensor
        temporarytens = padded_tensy
    target_tensors.append(temporarytens)
    
    
print (torch.cat(source_tensors).reshape(41316, 16))
print (torch.cat(target_tensors).reshape(41316, 16))
src_data = (torch.cat(source_tensors).reshape(41316, 16)).long()
tgt_data = (torch.cat(target_tensors).reshape(41316, 16)).long()


transformer = Transformer(src_vocab_size, tgt_vocab_size, d_model, num_heads, num_layers, d_ff, max_seq_length, dropout)




criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss(ignore_index=0)
optimizer = optim.Adam(transformer.parameters(), lr=0.001, betas=(0.9, 0.98), eps=1e-9)

transformer.train()

# Define the batch size and number of splits
batch_size = 32
num_splits = math.ceil(src_data.shape[0] / batch_size)

for epoch in range(313):
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    total_loss = 0.0
    
    for i in range(num_splits):
        start_idx = i * batch_size
        end_idx = min((i + 1) * batch_size, src_data.shape[0])
        
        src_batch = src_data[start_idx:end_idx]
        tgt_batch = tgt_data[start_idx:end_idx]
        
        output = transformer(src_batch, tgt_batch[:, :-1])
        loss = criterion(output.contiguous().view(-1, tgt_vocab_size), tgt_batch[:, 1:].contiguous().view(-1))
        
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        
        total_loss += loss.item()
    
    print(f"Epoch: {epoch+1}, Loss: {total_loss / num_splits}")
```

When running that code as it is nothing is outputted because at least as far as I am aware the cpu is much to slow to process the data.

I have tried sending devices to cuda using .to(device) where device is set up to be cuda, I have sent the transformer and any relevant data, I did get this error

```
 File "/home/rdrori/geneLocationLookupNetwork/pivotdevice.py", line 142, in forward
    src_mask, tgt_mask = self.generate_mask(src, tgt)
  File "/home/rdrori/geneLocationLookupNetwork/pivotdevice.py", line 138, in generate_mask
    tgt_mask = tgt_mask & nopeak_mask
RuntimeError: Expected all tensors to be on the same device, but found at least two devices, cuda:0 and CPU!
```

And have also tried to send tgt_mask, nopeak_mask and src_mask to cuda.